# How to reset /etc/sudoers file in Gnu/Linux, when locked out

Tags: linux, sudo, aws

I am using AWS Linux AMI2, I added `ec2-user ALL=(ALL) ALL` and saved the file.

Now when I run any command with `sudo` it displays `[sudo] password for ec2-user:`

How to reset this file?

Comment: Does this help, over on ServerFault - https://serverfault.com/q/144988/267016

Comment: Can you boot with some other OS image and mount the drive/volume from your VM?  Been a long time since I played with EC2, but Linode, DigitalOcean, etc provide for this with their vms....

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that line.

If the problem is that you don't know the password for `ec2-user`, then you must find some other way to get root access.

The line `ec2-user ALL=(ALL) ALL` means that `sudo` will ask for a password, because you didn't specify `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: True, but the question is how do I do this, if sudo is not working?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If you are locked out, you are locked out, nothing you can do. Otherwise, find a way to get access. Boot a rescue system, mount the image to another instance, or download the disk image, modify and upload.

Comment: @Yes than is the type of answer they are looking for. How to get un-locked out.

Answer (score -3):

By default, **sudo** requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command.

This behavior can be modified via the NOPASSWD tag.

For a single user, try

```
USERNAME ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

We can also modify the syntax to *allow specific commands* like

```
USERNAME ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /bin/ls
```

[Suoders](https://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.2/sudoers.man.html) manual has more details covering this topic

Comment: All very true, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: use the `pkexec visudo` to make the changes